# How to do fast sorting in sorted list when only one element is changed

Tags: c++, list

I need a list of elements that are always sorted. the operation involved is quite simple, for example, if the list is sorted from high to low, i only need three operations in some loop task:

```
while true do {
    list.sort() //sort the list that has hundreds of elements
    val = list[0] //get the first/maximum value in the list
    list.pop_front() //remove the first/maximum element

    ...//do some work here  

    list.push_back(new_elem)//insert a new element
    list.sort()
}
```

however, since I only add one elem at a time, and I have speed concern, I don't want the sorting go through all the elements, e.g., using bubble sorting. So I just wonder if there is a function  to insert the element in order? or whether the list::sort() function is smarter enough to use some kind of quick sort when only one element is added/modified?
Or maybe should I use deque for better speed performance if above are all the operations needed?

thanks alot!

Comment: If all you're doing is popping one element at a time, and pushing one element at a time, it sounds like you need a *heap*; not a sorted list. Have you considered [`std::priority_queue<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)?

Comment: If you need things to remain in sorted order, consider using a `std::set`. Inserts of new elements will be `O(log n)`.

Comment: Seems the list is no std::list, but more like a std::vector.

Comment: I suggest std::lower_bound

Comment: `list::sort` has no idea of the preconditions of the list so it has no way to optimize for your special case.

Comment: std:set should work for me, thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if you aren't locked into `std::list` then you should try `std::set` or `std::multiset`.

The `std::list::insert` method takes an iterator which specifies where to add the new item. You can use `std::lower_bound` to find the correct insertion point; it's not optimal without random access iterators but it still only does O(log n) comparisons.

P.S. don't use variable names that collide with built-in classes like `list`.

```
lst.sort(std::greater<T>()); //sort the list that has hundreds of elements
while true do {
    val = lst.front(); //get the first/maximum value in the list
    lst.pop_front(); //remove the first/maximum element

    ...//do some work here  

    std::list<T>::iterator it = std::lower_bound(lst.begin(), lst.end(), std::greater<T>());
    lst.insert(it, new_elem); //insert a new element
    // lst is already sorted
}
```